# Calling Fragment Activity from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listfragment

I'm initializing three fragments in my `FragmentActivity` that are actually tabs (`TabHost` and `ViewPager`), among those one is a list fragment.

Next I have another fragment activity with three tabs(fragments), Now what I want is on click of the list item of the list fragment, to call another fragment of 2nd fragment activity (which means that now the tabs that should come up are from another fragment activity ), also I want to pass some value from the selected list item to that next fragment. How can I achieve this?